# Which part of SemVer should I bump when deprecating supported Python version?

Tags: python, semantic-versioning, python-packaging

If a library supports both Python 2 and 3, and I want to deprecate support of Python 2, which part of SemVer should I bump, major or minor?

Comment: You could bump major, but frankly python2 is ancient so as long as you give some warning then you can just drop support quietly.

Comment: it's up to you, definetely not a patch one, if I were you I will choose a minor part since it doesn't drastically affect library API

Comment: On the other hand, it defenitelly breaks backward compatibility. @Azat Ibrakov

Comment: @tosh You are only *deprecating* support; nothing broke yet. When you actually *remove* support, then a major-number bump would be appropriate. The question is whether you make a new release *just* to deprecate Python-2 support.

Comment: I'm actually removing support.

Comment: @tosh Then that's not deprecation.

Comment: Either way, the answer explains both scenarios, 1) what the title asked and 2) what OP actually meant. If you feel the same way @tosh, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A deprecation doesn't break (or really change) anything; it's an official, explicit, advance warning that something *will* change in a future version.

The SemVar specification specifically says [to bump the minor version](https://semver.org/#spec-item-7):

> 7. Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. **It MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated.** It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements are introduced within the private code. It MAY include patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.

Once you *actually* remove support, that's a backwards-incompatible change: it *no longer works* for Python 2 users. Now would be the time [to bump the major version number](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8).

> 8. Major version X (X.y.z | X > 0) MUST be incremented if any backwards incompatible changes are introduced to the public API. It MAY include minor and patch level changes. Patch and minor version MUST be reset to 0 when major version is incremented.

Comment: Thanks! Although the question is closed, but the answer still does apply. ^_^